# Working with plugin ClassLoader and project ClassLoader

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

So I am developing one maven plugin where I need to modify the classloaders in order to work correctly. The problem is that I am not sure that I am modifying the correct classloader. What I'm doing is the following:

```
@Mojo(name = "aggregate", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST)
public class AcceptanceTestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  private static final String SYSTEM_CLASSLOADER_FIELD_NAME = "scl";


  @Parameter
  private String property;


  @Component
  public PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor;

  @Component
  public MavenProject mavenProject;

  @Override
  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    ClassLoader newClassLoader = null;

    List<String> runtimeClassPathElements;
    try {
      runtimeClassPathElements = mavenProject.getTestClasspathElements();
    } catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
      throw new MojoFailureException(MojoFailureMessages.UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_MESSAGE);
    }

    ClassRealm realm = pluginDescriptor.getClassRealm();

    ClassRealm modifiedRealm= new ClassRealm( realm.getWorld(), realm.getId(),  realm.getParentClassLoader());

    try {
      for (String element : runtimeClassPathElements) {
        File elementFile = new File(element);
        modifiedRealm.addURL(elementFile.toURI().toURL());

      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       throw new MojoFailureException(MojoFailureMessages.UNRESOLVED_CLASSES_MESSAGE);
    }

    pluginDescriptor.setClassRealm(modifiedRealm);
```

So I am getting the ClassRealm and I'am making slight changes to the UCP(removing some jars) and after that I set the newly created ClassRealm to the project descriptor. I am also changing the ContextClassLoader and the SystemClassLoader as the project I am executing my plugin on are using them for some interactions. These two are working fine- they are changed and the plugin is working fine with them. The problem is the plugin classloader. Because for some reason when executing my plugin on one project it is looking in the plugin ClassRealm and searching for the needed jars from there. But the code I put above is not fully correct, because when I come to the part where the execution of the plugin is looking in the plugin ClassRealm it is not the modified one- it gets another reference, which I don't know where it comes from. What I think is that I am not setting the ClassRealm correctly or I am missing something else.